# Qual o problema com a utilização do método replace de string no meu código em TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, replace

Boa tarde, pessoal. Estou utilizando a linguagem TypeScript pela primeira vez em um "projeto de fim de semana" no desenvolvimento de uma extensão para o VSCode. Realizei pesquisas pela documentação do método, mas continuo sem compreender a onde estou errando. Imagino que seja um problema "bobo" devido a inexperiência com a linguagem. O que está acontecendo é que o uso do método replace de string não está de fato substituindo todos as strings retiradas de dois vetores. A função retiraPalavrasSelecaoCodigoPython não está retirando todas as strings de um trecho de código do Python, também passado como string pela variável selecaoCodigo. A seguir o código:

```js
function executaExtensaoPython(selecaoCodigo:string, formatoArquivo:string):void{
    var alfabetoPython : string[] = ["#", "selfie", ".", "=", "get", "set", "(", ")", ":", ","];
    var alfabetoIgnorar : string[] = [" "];
    var selecaoCodigoModificada;

    //Retirando palavras do alfabeto das linguagens Python e Ignorar
    selecaoCodigoModificada = retiraPalavrasSelecaoCodigoPython(selecaoCodigo, alfabetoIgnorar, alfabetoPython);
    console.log("\nSELEÇÃO MODIFICADA = " + selecaoCodigoModificada);
}
function retiraPalavrasSelecaoCodigoPython(selecaoCodigo : string, alfabetoIgnorar : string[], alfabetoPython : string[]) : string{
    for(var i=0;i<alfabetoIgnorar.length;i++){
        selecaoCodigo = selecaoCodigo.replace(alfabetoIgnorar[i], "");
    }
    for(var i=0;i<alfabetoPython.length;i++){
        selecaoCodigo = selecaoCodigo.replace(alfabetoPython[i], "");
    }
    return selecaoCodigo;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A função retiraPalavrasSelecaoCodigoPython está substituindo apenas a primeira ocorrência de cada elemento que se deseja remover. Uma forma de substituir todas as ocorrễncias é utilizar split seguido do join:

```
function retiraPalavrasSelecaoCodigoPython(selecaoCodigo : string, alfabetoIgnorar : string[], alfabetoPython : string[]) : string{
    for(var i=0;i<alfabetoIgnorar.length;i++){
        selecaoCodigo = selecaoCodigo.split(alfabetoIgnorar[i]).join("");
    }
    for(var i=0;i<alfabetoPython.length;i++){
        selecaoCodigo = selecaoCodigo.split(alfabetoPython[i]).join("");
    }
    return selecaoCodigo;
}
```

Para mais detalhes sobre isso, consulte essa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string

Comment: Muito obrigado, Matheus.